# jquery selector by child tag value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

see below code.

xml value

```
<root>
   <item>
      <name>name 1</name>          
      <class>A</class>
      <age>15</age>
    </item>
   <item>
      <name>name 2</name>         
      <class>A</class>
      <age>15</age>
    </item>
   <item>
      <name>name 3</name>         
      <class>B</class>
      <age>15</age>
    </item>
   <item>
      <name>name 4</name>         
      <class>A</class>
      <age>16</age>
    </item>
   <item>
      <name>name 5</name>
      <class>B</class>
      <age>15</age>
    </item>
</root>
```

i want to retrieve items that are having class = "A" AND age = 15. How can i we do this using jQuery selector.

something like this

$items = $(root).find("item age='25'&&class='A'").

Comment: something like find(item age = 25).find(class=A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this.

```
$("item").filter(function(i){
   return $(this).find("class").text()=="A" &&  $(this).find("age").text()=="15"
       });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/xbMac/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $items = $(root).find('item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('age').text() == 25 && $(this).find('class').text() == 'a';
})
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 15 seconds! Nice.

Comment: @JoeFletch Hehe. A small note on your code: `i` should be renamed to something like `el` or `element`, since its a dom object and not the index in this case.

Comment: I checked the value on `i` and the value of `el` / `element` and it is still just the index of the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem here what you can do-

```
var $items = [];
$('age').each(function(){
 if($('age').html()=="15"){
   $item = $(this).parent();
   if($('class',$item).html()=="A")
      $items.push($item);
 });
```

now $items is array of all items that are having class = "A" AND age = 15.